Approximating a given subharmonic function on a Riemann surface, with smooth functions
Let $\Sigma$ be a (connected) Riemann surface and let $u$ be subharmonic on $\Sigma$.
I would like to approximate $u$ from above with smooth subharmonic functions, in the following sense:

For any $U\Subset\Sigma$, there exists a sequence of functions $u_n\in C^\infty(U)$ with the following property: $u_n$ is subharmonic on $U$, $u_{n+1}\leq u_n$ on $U$, and $u_n\to u$ pointwise on $U$.

When $\Sigma$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, I can construct the sequence $u_n$ by taking convolution of $u$ with a suitable mollifier. But I guess taking convolution doesn't make sense on a general Riemann surface. What techniques should I use to prove this?
